# filter values of main table from foreign key table view

Tags: python, django

I a trying to display the values of a foreign key table sorted upon the values of other foreign table.
***I am unable to find a way to show all the type of categories available in a specific city in the views.***

```
#models.py
class restaurent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Type', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter a brief description of the restaurent")
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', help_text="Select a city for this book")


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('res-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Type(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,help_text="Enter the category")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,help_text="Enter a city")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name
```

```
#views.py

class citydetail(generic.ListView):
    model = City
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(citydetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['test'] = Type.objects.all()
```

From the above view I am able to get all the restaurants present that specific city, ***but along with that I want to find the type categories available in the specific city. A help is very much appreciated***

Comment: please post what you have tried, it will be easy to figure out where you are stuck.

Comment: I have added the views code and explained where I am stuck, could you guys please look in